# Relationship between Entities are not persisting

Tags: objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship

In my application, I have Category and Sub_Category entities which are having a to-many relation ship between them.

Firstly, when the App runs for the first time the relation attribute(category_subCategory) is working as shown below:

```
2012-04-11 04:03:39.344 SupplyTrackerApp[27031:12f03] Saved
2012-04-11 04:03:47.423 SupplyTrackerApp[27031:fb03] Category<Category: 0x6ba4e90> (entity: Category; id: 0x6e95620 <x-coredata://00E5784E-D032-41DD-BD60-B85B0BBF8E31/Category/p1> ; data: {
    categoryID = 1;
    categoryName = Antiques;
    "category_SubCategory" =     (
        "0x6ebb4f0 <x-coredata://00E5784E-D032-41DD-BD60-B85B0BBF8E31/Sub_Category/p1>"
    );
    catetogoryDescription = "Contains a Sub categories related to Antique pieces";
})
```

But when I exit the app an restart the application, that relationship does exists. The output looks like this..

```
2012-04-11 04:05:04.455 SupplyTrackerApp[27038:fb03] In Cell for row at index path
2012-04-11 04:05:05.548 SupplyTrackerApp[27038:fb03] Category<Category: 0x6ecaca0> (entity: Category; id: 0x6eb4ab0 <x-coredata://00E5784E-D032-41DD-BD60-B85B0BBF8E31/Category/p1> ; data: {
    categoryID = 1;
    categoryName = Antiques;
    "category_SubCategory" = "<relationship fault: 0x6ecf0a0 'category_SubCategory'>";
    catetogoryDescription = "Contains a Sub categories related to Antique pieces";
})
```

Here is where I'm calling the create entities..

```
-(void) loadDataIntoDocument{


    NSLog(@"In Load Data");

    dispatch_queue_t fetch=dispatch_queue_create("Data Fetcher", NULL);

    dispatch_async(fetch, ^{



            [Sub_Category createSubCategory:context];


            NSError *error;


            if (![context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }else {


                NSLog(@"Saved");
            }


    });




    dispatch_release(fetch);


}
```

So the Sub_Category+Create Category file has the following code.

```
+(Sub_Category *) createSubCategory:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context{


    Sub_Category *subCategory=nil;

    NSFetchRequest *request=[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Sub_Category"];

    request.predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subCategoryID=%@", @"11"];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor=[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"subCategoryName" ascending:YES];

    request.sortDescriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];



    NSError *error;

    NSArray *matches=[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (!matches||[matches count]>1) {
        ///errorrrrrrrrrr
    } else if([matches count]==0) {


        subCategory=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sub_Category" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        subCategory.subCategoryID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", 11];

        subCategory.subCategoryName=@"Antiquities";

        subCategory.subCategoryDescription=@"Contains several products related to antiquities";



        subCategory.subCategory_Category =[Category createCategory:context];

    }else {
        subCategory=[matches lastObject];
    }



    return subCategory;



}
```

And then I'm calling the Category+Create Category file which has the following code.

```
+(Category *) createCategory:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context{


    Category *category=nil;

    NSFetchRequest *request=[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Category"];

    request.predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categoryID=%@", @"1"];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor=[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"categoryName" ascending:YES];

    request.sortDescriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];


    NSError *error;

    NSArray *matches=[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (!matches||[matches count]>1) {
        ///errorrrrrrrrrr
            } else if([matches count]==0) {

                category=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:context];

                category.categoryID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",1];

                category.categoryName=@"Antiques";

                category.catetogoryDescription=@"Contains a Sub categories related to Antique pieces";




            }else {
                category=[matches lastObject];
            }






    return category;

}
```

Can anyone help me out regarding this..

I'm stuck on this from few days...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what is going wrong. Does NSLog()ing the error from the executeFetchRequest: tell you anything?

Comment: Its not giving any error while performing the executeFetchRequest. Even its showing the relationship between them when the application is running for the first time. But, when i exit the application and fetch the Category entity the relationship value doesn't exist.

It shows something like:
"<relationship fault: 0x6e84890 'category_SubCategory'>"

Answer (score 1):

I looks like you're using `dispatch_async` to do the `-save:` in the background. This is probably violating the "thread confinement" rules for dealing with an `NSManagedObject` (in short, they should only be used in the thread they were created on. Same applies to any objects fetched from them).

For more information on how to do concurrency with Core Data, see [this WWDC Session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=118).

Try only using your Core Data stack (and any objects you fetch from it) from the main thread.